# CKEditor allow pasteFilter and enterMode at the same time

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I want different formatting style while pasting a text in the editor and while writing.
But when I define `enterMode : CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR`, it applies for the pasted text as well and removes the pasted text formatting and tags. i.e. It overrides the `pasteFilter: 'semantic-content'` behavior.

Is there any way I can keep both?

Following are my config:

```
editor = CKEDITOR.replace("annotationEditor", {
        toolbarGroups: [
        { name: 'basicstyles', groups: [ 'basicstyles', 'cleanup' ] }
        ],
        removePlugins : 'uploadimage',
        pasteFilter: 'semantic-content',
        enterMode : CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR,
        /*shiftEnterMode: CKEDITOR.ENTER_P,*/
        extraPlugins : 'maxlength',
        removeButtons : removeButtons,
        pasteFromWordRemoveFontStyles: false,
        autoParagraph : false
    });
```

I tried following as well but did not work:

```
CKEDITOR.instances['annotationEditor'].on('key', function(e) {
        e.editor.on('change', function (event){
            if(e.data.keyCode == 13){ // Do this code when ENTER is pressed
                CKEDITOR.config.enterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR;
                CKEDITOR.config.forceEnterMode = true;
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want different formatting style while pasting a text in the editor and while writing.

If you want to use `enterMode` set to `BR` and paste rich content then if your [ACF](https://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_acf) settings allow all the tags you want to paste, I would suggest using [paste event](https://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-paste) listener with a very low priority and `dontFilter` flag set to true (you could do some filtering of your own in that filter as well). If this won't help I can't think of any other way to do it.

If on the other hand you want to have e.g. `enterMode` set to `P` and you want to paste content formatted like in `BR` mode that you could use [forcePasteAsPlainText](https://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-forcePasteAsPlainText) setting together with events like [pasteFromWord](https://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-pasteFromWord), [afterPasteFromWord](https://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-afterPasteFromWord), [afterPaste](https://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-afterPaste), [paste](https://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-paste) to do some extra filtering.